# String changed after writing to, and reading from file

Tags: java, signature, randomaccessfile

I'm writing some data to a file (A string in this case, but could be anything since I'm using byte[]), after this I'm reading it and comparing the result. When I compare both byte[]'s, they look the same to me, but running `.equals()` returns `false`.

Please find my code below:

```
private void sign(ActionEvent e) throws Exception {
    byte[] data = read(file);

    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    sig.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());
    sig.update(data);
    byte[] signatureBytes = sig.sign();

    String newFilePath = "output.file";

    int signatureLength = signatureBytes.length;
    String signString = new BASE64Encoder().encode(signatureBytes);

    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(newFilePath, "rw");
    raf.writeInt(signatureLength);
    raf.write(signatureBytes);
    raf.write(data);
    raf.close();

    verify(newFilePath, signatureBytes, data);
}

private void verify(String path, byte[] signature, byte[] originalMessage) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(path);

    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f.getPath(), "r");
    int sigLength = raf.readInt();
    byte[] signatureBytes = new byte[sigLength];
    raf.read(signatureBytes);

    Long remainingLength = raf.length() - 1 - sigLength;
    byte[] message = new byte[remainingLength.intValue()];
    raf.read(message);

    raf.close();

    System.out.println("==== VERIFYING SIGNATURE ====");
    String originalString = new BASE64Encoder().encode(signature);
    String newString = new BASE64Encoder().encode(signatureBytes);

    System.out.println("originalString\n" + originalString);
    System.out.println("newString\n" + newString);

    System.out.println("Signatures match: " + newString.equals(originalString));

    System.out.println("==== VERIFYING MESSAGE ====");
    String originalMessageString = new String(originalMessage);
    String messageString = new String(message);
    System.out.println("originalMessageString = " + originalMessageString);
    System.out.println("messageString = " + messageString);
    System.out.println("Messages match: " + originalMessageString.equals(messageString));

    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    sig.initVerify(keyPair.getPublic());
    sig.update(message);

    System.out.println(sig.verify(signatureBytes)); // false
}
```

I get the following output: (The file is a txt file containing the string "Hoi")

```
==== VERIFYING SIGNATURE ====
originalString
DU00HopnNgOnwPL4Y50lwR5CJFVCRqsj3hkdyareMqHPe4RKdCUr2FSNEuh0yq5LyzcP96MNDzNJ
jVTTI8+V3SPMDzQIjw4Ibb+xM3/XZHQi5ej8XfVXao234QytRD5y1bWKxlZEh4BlnzXcqD9tmANB
BOQTG3P15Ea0fFkDYpg=
newString
DU00HopnNgOnwPL4Y50lwR5CJFVCRqsj3hkdyareMqHPe4RKdCUr2FSNEuh0yq5LyzcP96MNDzNJ
jVTTI8+V3SPMDzQIjw4Ibb+xM3/XZHQi5ej8XfVXao234QytRD5y1bWKxlZEh4BlnzXcqD9tmANB
BOQTG3P15Ea0fFkDYpg=
Signatures match: true
==== VERIFYING MESSAGE ====
originalMessageString = Hoi
messageString = Hoi   
Messages match: false  <------ WTF
false
```

Any help on resolving this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have some space after messageString. Try

```
System.out.println("Messages match: " + originalMessageString.equals(messageString.trim()));
```

Comment: Thanks, it does seem like there was a space somewhere. I'd like to find where it is. comparing `originalMessage` and `message` using `Arrays.equals(originalMessage, message)` does return false, so I guess I'm reading too many bytes?

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong offset when calculating `remainingLength`. I deducted 1 from the total file length - signature length to compensate for the first integer in the file. I then realised that integers are 4 Bytes long. Changing this number to 4 fixed it.

As such, this line should be:

```
Long remainingLength = raf.length() - 4 - sigLength;
```